# Меню на PHP и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы меню отображалось в select /select

```html
<?php 

function menu() {

$menu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `menu`");

$arr_cat = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($menu) != 0) {
 
 for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($menu); $i++) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($menu, MYSQL_ASSOC);
  if(empty($arr_cat[$row['parent_id']])) {
   $arr_cat[$row['parent_id']] = array();
  }
  $arr_cat[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
 }
 return $arr_cat;
}
}

function view_cat($arr, $parent_id = 0) {
 if(empty($arr[$parent_id])) {
  return;
 }
 
 echo "<ul>";
 for($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$parent_id]); $i++) {
  echo "<li> <a href=".$arr[$parent_id][$i]['link'].">".$arr[$parent_id][$i]['title']." ";
  view_cat($arr, $arr[$parent_id][$i]['id']);
  echo "</a>";
  echo "</li>";
 }
 echo "</ul>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Заменить `<ul>` на `<select>`, а `<li>` на `<option>` ?

Comment: не работает так

Comment: Если не работает, значит вы этого не сделали - другого объяснения нет, так как не видно, как вы и где это сделали.

Comment: я заменил все как Вы и сказали, в select оформляется только первый пункт меню, остальные пункты даже не выводятся

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой элемент select специально для таких нужд.

```css
.mySelect
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Arial' sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #111;
    line-height:30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Выберете опцию.</h1>
    <select class="mySelect" name="Select">
      //Выбраная 
      <option value="1" selected>One</option>
      //Отключенная
      <option value="2" disabled>Two</option>
      //Обычная
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Спасибо

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/select зайдите туда там про все ясно и подробно

Comment: В разных браузерах результат может отличатся но смысл тот же :/

Comment: Я знаю что такое select и как его выводить, но вопрос в том как сделать именно с тем кодом который я выложил.

Comment: ul заменить на select. li на option. Добавить значения к option и повесить обрпботчик на js

Comment: Не вижу в этом смысла хоть убейте